# Add additional properties to IdentityUser ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity

**Users table**

```
 [Table("Users")]
   public  class User : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<User> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Gender")]
        public string Gender { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Date of birth")]
        public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    }
```

**MyContext Class**

```
 public class myContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
    {
        public myContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }
        public static myContext Create()
        {
            return new myContext();
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("Users", "dbo");
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles", "dbo");
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles", "dbo");
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims", "dbo");
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogins", "dbo");
        }

    }
```

This is creating two tables

1. AspNetUsers - with additiona fields
2. Users - with default fields

Note sure what am I missing here. How can I have the additional fields also in `Users` table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the line in `OnModelCreating` in `myContext`:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("Users", "dbo");
```

to:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users", "dbo");
```

Right now, it is creating two tables because you have defined `IdentityUser` type to be used to create table named `Users` and one default table is getting created against `IdentityUser` type.